# How can I strip line breaks from my XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I have this XSLT:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="math">
    <img class="math">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?<xsl:value-of
            select="text()" /></xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</xsl:template>
```

Which is being applied to this XML (notice the line break):

```
<math>\text{average} = \alpha \times \text{data} + (1-\alpha) \times
    \text{average}</math>
```

Unfortunately, the transform creates this:

```
<img
    class="math"
    src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\text{average} = \alpha \times \text{data} + (1-\alpha) \times&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;\text{average}" />
```

Notice the whitespace character literals. Although it works, it's awfully messy. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer, which provides a complete and simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is not sufficient to use the [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) function as it is leaving mid-spaces!**

**Here is a simple and complete solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="math">
    <img class="math">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?<xsl:value-of
            select="translate(.,' &#9;&#10;', '')" /></xsl:attribute>
    </img>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<math>\text{average} = \alpha \times \text{data} + (1-\alpha) \times
    \text{average}</math>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<img class="math" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\text{average}=\alpha\times\text{data}+(1-\alpha)\times\text{average}" />
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the XPath 1.0** [**`translate()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) **function** to strip off all unwanted characters.
2. **There is no need to use the [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function here** -- it may not be possible to use it, because it is only available in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Oddly enough, I stumbled across a similar solution myself: `translate(normalize-space(), ' ', '')`. Although I've now realized that I probably want to URL-escape the spaces to `%20`, rather than remove them. Can `translate` be used for that purpose?

Comment: @Eric: No, `translate()` only substitutes char for char or eats a char. Please, ask another question and I'll show how to replace a space with %20. If you have XSLT 2.0 you can use the XPath 2.0 `replace()` function to do this. In XSLT 1.0 there are other ways.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, I could use `url-encode()`. But I can't use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are generating the text. But there are two ways:

1. You can use the [xsl:strip-spac](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp)e element that is available in XSLT.
2. If you generate the text during XSLT process, then another way to achieve will be to make use of string process methods: [normalize-space and replace methods](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The [normalize-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function strips leading and trailing whitespace and replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. With no parameters, it will operate on the string value of the context node.

```
<xsl:template match="math">
    <img class="math">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" /></xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</xsl:template>
```

Also your stylesheet can be simplified by using an attribute value template instead of `xsl:attribute`.

```
<xsl:template match="math">
    <img class="math" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?{normalize-space()}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem as there are still some mid-spaces left. See my answer for a solution that really solves the problem.